# Performance issues when pushing data at a constant rate to Elasticsearch on multiple indexes at the same time

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

We are experiencing some performance issues or anomalies on a elasticsearch specifically on a system we are currently building.

**The requirements:**
We need to capture data for multiple of our customers,  who will query and report on them on a near real time basis. All the documents received are the same format with the same properties and are in a flat structure (all fields are of primary type and no nested objects). We want to keep each customer’s information separate from each other.

**Frequency of data received and queried:**
We receive data for each customer at a fluctuating rate of 200 to 700 documents per second – with the peak being in the middle of the day.
Queries will be mostly aggregations over around 12 million documents per customer – histogram/percentiles to show patterns over time and the occasional raw document retrieval to find out what happened a particular point in time. We are aiming to serve 50 to 100 customer at varying rates of documents inserted – the smallest one could be 20 docs/sec to the largest one peaking at 1000 docs/sec for some minutes.

**How are we storing the data:**
Each customer has one index per day. For example, if we have 5 customers, there will be a total of 35 indexes for the whole week. The reason we break it per day is because it is mostly the latest two that get queried with occasionally the remaining others. We also do it that way so we can delete older indexes independently of customers (some may want to keep 7 days, some 14 days’ worth of data)

**How we are inserting:**
We are sending data in batches of 10 to 2000 – every second. One document is around 900bytes raw.

Environment
AWS C3-Large – 3 nodes
All indexes are created with 10 shards with 2 replica for the test purposes
Both Elasticsearch 1.3.2 and 1.4.1

**What we have noticed:**

If I push data to one index only, Response time starts at 80 to 100ms for each batch inserted when the rate of insert is around 100 documents per second.  I ramp it up and I can reach 1600 before the rate of insert goes to close to 1sec per batch and when I increase it to close to 1700, it will hit a wall at some point because of concurrent insertions and the time will spiral to 4 or 5 seconds. Saying that, if I reduce the rate of inserts, Elasticsearch recovers nicely. CPU usage increases as rate increases.

If I push to 2 indexes concurrently, I can reach a total of 1100 and CPU goes up to 93% around 900 documents per second.
If I push to 3 indexes concurrently, I can reach a total of 150 and CPU goes up to 95 to 97%. I tried it many times. The interesting thing is that response time is around 109ms at the time. I can increase the load to 900 and response time will still be around 400 to 600 but CPU stays up.

**Question:**

Looking at our requirements and findings above, is the design convenient for what’s asked? Are there any tests that I can do to find out more? Is there any setting that I need to check (and change)?

Answer (score 4):

I've been hosting thousands of Elasticsearch clusters on AWS over at https://bonsai.io for the last few years, and have had many a capacity planning conversation that sound like this.

First off, it sounds to me like you have a pretty good cluster design and test rig going here. My first intuition here is that you are legitimately approaching the limits of your c3.large instances, and will want to bump up to a c3.xlarge (or bigger) fairly soon.

An index per tenant per day could be reasonable, if you have relatively few tenants. You may consider an index per day for all tenants, using filters to focus your searches on specific tenants. And unless there are obvious cost savings to discarding old data, then filters should suffice to enforce data retention windows as well.

The primary benefit of segmenting your indices per tenant would be to move your tenants between different Elasticsearch clusters. This could help if you have some tenants with wildly larger usage than others. Or to reduce the potential for Elasticsearch's cluster state management to be a single point of failure for all tenants.

A few other things to keep in mind that may help explain the performance variance you're seeing.

Most importantly here, indexing is incredibly CPU bottlenecked. This makes sense, because Elasticsearch and Lucene are fundamentally just really fancy string parsers, and you're sending piles of strings. (Piles are a legitimate unit of measurement here, right?) Your primary bottleneck is going to be the number and speed of your CPU cores.

In order to take the best advantage of your CPU resources while indexing, you should consider the number of primary shards you're using. I'd recommend starting with three primary shards to distribute the CPU load evenly across the three nodes in your cluster.

For production, you'll almost certainly end up on larger servers. The goal is for your total CPU load for your peak indexing requirements ends up under 50%, so you have some additional overhead for processing your searches. Aggregations are also fairly CPU hungry. The extra performance overhead is also helpful for gracefully handling any other unforeseen circumstances.

You mention pushing to multiple indices concurrently. I would avoid concurrency when bulk updating into Elasticsearch, in favor of batch updating with the Bulk API. You can bulk load documents for multiple indices with the cluster-level `/_bulk` endpoint. Let Elasticsearch manage the concurrency internally without adding to the overhead of parsing more HTTP connections.

That's just a quick introduction to the subject of performance benchmarking. The Elasticsearch docs have a good article on [Hardware](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html) which may also help you plan your cluster size.